# How can I get output from command line into condition in script?

Tags: python, linux

I tried this:

```
import os

if os.system('somecommand') == 'output from command':

    do_something()
```

But it didn't worked. How can I do it? What library should I use?

When I use solution with subprocess below I get this errorcode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `os.system()` is the exit code of the process, not whatever it outputs to stdin. You want to use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead:

```
import subprocess

if subprocess.check_output('somecommand') == 'output from command':
```