# python subprocess output without \n

Tags: python

Here is a simple script running subprocess that retrieves IP from the `ifconfig` command output from the terminal.
I have noticed that `subprocess.check_output()` always returns a value with `\n`.

I desire to get a return value **without `\n`**.
How can this be done?

```
$ python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("ifconfig en0 | awk '{ print $2}' | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'", shell=True)
'129.194.246.245\n'
```

Comment: `echo` adds that newline..

Comment: no not only. If I run `subprocess.check_output("ifconfig en0 | awk '{ print $2}' | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'", shell=True)`  which retrieves my ip address on bash mac OS X, the return line is also present

Comment: echo -n to not have echo newline. Or add .strip() at the end of the subprocess line

Comment: Just `rstrip` then off, also you don't need to use shell=True

Comment: @Jupiter: Because that newline was present in the output of `grep`. If the output *in your terminal* contains a newline (so the prompt for the next command starts at column 0 on the next line), then you'll get it in the `check_command` output *too*.

Comment: @Jupiter,  you could also parse all the output using just python quite easily

Comment: It is rather a large change to replace `echo` with your `ifconfig | awk | grep -o` command, invalidating a lot of the answers. Not that your assertion is any more true because of it.

Comment: @Jupiter it seems that you're a PHP programmer. Do note that PHP `exec` explicitly (and incorrectly IMHO) removes trailing newlines from the returned output.

Comment: Funny, I'm having the opposite problem.  `subprocess.check_output(["apt", "list", "--installed"])` returns everything jumbled together instead of the line by line output I'd get by running `apt list --installed' directly.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For a generic way :

```
subprocess.check_output("echo hello world", shell=True).strip()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer *why* there is a newline in the output; either for the `echo` or the `grep` output. Hint: it's not `check_output()` that adds it.

Comment: The question was not why but how to remove it :-D I guess the answer is that command line binaries add a new line at the end of their outputs to have a nice shell prompt juste after (on a different line).

Comment: I think we just differ in interpretation of the question. *I have noticed that `subprocess.check_output()` always returns a value with `\n`*. And the OP altered the question to show that even with `grep -o` they still get that newline (as if to prove the answers that point to echo as the source of the newline are wrong).

Comment: `strip` might be a bad idea since leading (or trailing) ASCII whitespaces in the output of a command (not shell!) can be important.

Answer (score 9):

`subprocess.check_output()` does **not** add a newline. `echo` does. You can use the `-n` switch to suppress the newline, but you have to *avoid* using the shell built-in implementation (so use `/bin/echo`):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('/bin/echo -n hello world', shell=True)
'hello world'
```

If you use `echo -n` instead, you could get the string `'-n hello world\n'`, as not all `sh` implementations support the `-n` switch support `echo` (OS X for example).

You could always use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) or [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove whitespace, of course, but don't blame `subprocess` here:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output('echo hello world', shell=True).rstrip('\n')
'hello world'
```

Your question update added a more complex example using `awk` and `grep`:

```
subprocess.check_output("ifconfig en0 | awk '{ print $2}' | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'", shell=True)
```

Here *grep* adds the (final) newline. `grep -o` may print *just* the matching text, but still adds a newline to separate matches. See the [`grep` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control):

> -o
>   --only-matching
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, **with each such part on a separate output line.**

Emphasis mine.

You can add a [`tr -d '\n'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/remove-end-of-line-characters-from-stdout-multiple-lines-into-a-single-line) at the end to remove any newlines from the output of your pipe:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ifconfig en0 | awk '{ print $2}' | "
...     "grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | "
...     "tr -d '\n'", shell=True)
'172.17.174.160'
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a question about echo, `rstrip` is what the OP needs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that *depends*. And it is important to point out that the assumption that `check_process` adds this newline is incorrect.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: given the change to the question, the OP is almost certainly still claiming that the newline was added by `check_output`. That you can remove newlines with `str.rstrip()` doesn't matter here.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think Martijn's point **still** is to demonstrate that `subprocess.check_output` does not add **any** newlines at all, which you can only demonstrate by piping to a command that surely removes the newlines. Upvoted.

Comment: It’s important to point out *why* something doesn’t work the way OP is expecting things. Good answers do that instead of just throwing out a random solution which *works* but has no reference to OP’s original approach. We’re here to learn and to teach things, not to give out code that everyone should just copy/paste without thinking. – This is a good answer!

Comment: This helped me where nothing else did. I was sending "echo -n XXX | pbcopy" to `subprocess.check_output` instead of "/bin/echo -n XXX | pbcopy".

With the former, the output is "-n XXX\n" rather than "XXX"
With the latter, I got the desired "XXX".

Answer (score 3):

This is what you have :

```
$ python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("ifconfig eth0 | awk '{ print $2}' | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'", shell=True)
'172.31.94.116\n'
```

Try this instead :

```
$ python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("ifconfig eth0 | awk '{ print $2}' | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'", shell=True).strip()
'172.31.94.116'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `str.rstrip` any newline or use what Martijn suggests, you can also parse the output using python with the need to *awk* or *grep* which won't add any newlines:

You can split:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", "en0"])

for line in out.splitlines():
    if line.lstrip().startswith("inet "):
        print(line.split()[1].split(":", 2)[1])
        print(ip.search(line))
        break
```

Or use your own regex:

```
import  re

out = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", "en0"])

print(re.search('([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}', out).group())
```

The point being you don't need awk or grep.

If you want to match ipv4 or ipv6 and also catch when there is an error returned  i.e no such interface you can catch a `CalledProcessError` which will be raised for any non zero exit status, it is easy use the regex for ipv4 but for ipv6 it is simpler to use `inet6` to grab the ipv6 address.

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
import re

def get_ip(iface, ipv="ipv4"):
    try:
       out = check_output(["ifconfig", iface])
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.message)
        return False
    try:
        if ipv == "ipv4":
            return re.search('([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}', out).group()
        return re.search("(?<=inet6 addr:)(.*?)(?=/)", out).group().lstrip()
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("No {} address for interface {}".format(ipv, iface))
        return False
```

Demo:

```
In [2]: get_ip("wlan0")
Out[2]: '192.168.43.168'

In [3]: get_ip("wlan0","ipv6")
Out[3]: 'fe80::120b:a9ff:fe03:bb10'

In [4]: get_ip("wlan1","ipv6")
wlan1: error fetching interface information: Device not found   
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: `str.lstrip('addr:')`? That'll remove the characters `a`, `d`, `r` and `:` from the start. In any order. What if I have an IPv6 address?

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Am, then you would look for inet6, you could also split once on `:`, there are lots of options.

Comment: The point being that you should not use `lstrip` to remove a prefix.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,also can you explain how the OP's regex coulf match an ipv6 address?

Comment: Can you please see past the IPv6 example and see that using `str.lstrip()` is a *not a good idea* that we have had to shoot down so many times in so many duplicate questions? It'll remove a set of characters. That it works here is *coincidence*. You could have used `.lstrip(' :adr')` and get the same outcome without the initial space, for IPv4 addresses. And then someone replaces the line with one that also matches IPv6, uses a similar lstrip (because they don't realise this mistake) and you got a bug anyway.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham downvoted since your solution is broken, though in this exact situation seems to produce the correct output.

Comment: @ila, how is it broken?

Comment: See the comments above. No need to repeat what has been said. `strip`, `rstrip` and `lstrip` are horrible choices for removing fixed prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: The gist of your answer @PadraicCunningham is correct in that the OP had an XY problem, however your code is not very robust. Notice that `:` and `a` and `d` are all also valid characters in inet6 addresses, so if you use `lstrip` to remove the prefix as you did, you could possibly strip part of the address as well.

Comment: @Ilja, there are no situations where what is in the answer will break as the OP is looking for the ip address, it can easily be changed to `line.split()[1].split(":", 2)[1]` or to use their regex pattern, the main point is you don't need awk and grep.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham as always, the answer should strive to be useful to other readers too, and so advocating possibly dangerous constructs rewards you a downvote. As you yourself now demonstrate, it would've been easy to use something that does the right thing from the start. Sorry for the holier than thou kind of text, but I actually hope that you and others give me the same lecturing in similar situations. Learning is fun.

Comment: @Ilja, well now there are two solutions using a regex and splitting.  I have a feeling the toys won't all be put back in the pram thought ;)

Comment: Aye, much better :P This way the future us don't need to answer the multitude of "My `strip("All the characters ever")` removes more than it should" questions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, the OP is looking for an ipv4 address, so as I also pointed out to Martijn, an ipv6 address does not come into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Met the same problem in JVM world in com-lihaoyi/os-lib library. My case is /bin/bash with "-c" flag and AWK with its`s own program as argument.

I think the root problem is print function which print text and add move cursor to next line

As for AWK: the solution is to use printf instead of build-in in AWK print (but it will be difficult to put first new line symbol)
For echo: use "-n" flag

[image]