# Cannot change variable state from within if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, global-variables

I can't change the value of a variable outside an if statement with code within that if statement.

```
#import lines here

alarm_active=False
alarm_on=False

def handle(msg):
    global alarm_active
    global alarm_on
    #other lines of code

while 1:
    print 'while works'
    if alarm_active==True:
        print 'alarm works'
        foo = subprocess.check_output("python one_sensor_alarm.py", shell=True)
        print foo
        if foo == 'chiuso':
            print "intrusion"
            alarm_on=True
            alarm_active=False
    time.sleep(1)
```

The two variables `alarm_active` and `alarm_on` are declared global within the `handle(msg)` method.
When `foo == 'chiuso'`, the code within that if is not executed.
Is an issue of using global variables?

Comment: you haven't properly indented the while loop... your while loop immediately executes and handle is never used period.  also why are you doing `while 1:` instead of `while true:`?

Comment: Are you sure that `check_output` returns exactly "chiuso", not e.g. "chiuso\n"? Have you tried it?

Comment: @snb It's the same, but you're right, True is more "readable". Thank Anton, the problem was i forgot \n :)

Comment: If _"alarm works"_ gets printed then the comment of Anton Kachurin has most likely the problem: [check this Stack Overflow entry about subprocess output with newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422572/python-subprocess-output-without-n)

Answer (score 1):

- `alarm_active` will never be `true` according to your code snippet.
- If we assume that we set `alarm_active=true` then `if foo == "chiuso":` will not work if `python one_sensor_alarm.py` is returning `\n` at the end of string. So try this code:

```python
import subprocess
import time

alarm_active = True
alarm_on = False


def handle(msg):
    global alarm_active
    global alarm_on
    # other lines of code


while 1:
    print('while works')
    if alarm_active is True:
        print('alarm works')
        foo = subprocess.check_output("python one_sensor_alarm.py", shell=True)
        print("foo %s" % repr(foo))
        if foo.strip() == "chiuso":
            print("intrusion")
            alarm_on = True
            alarm_active = False
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: There is no need to make either `if alarm_active is True` or `if alarm_active == True`, as alarm_active is boolean, just use it like `if alarm_active:`.

Comment: @derkan alarm_active become True after handle(msg) do something