# Python subprocess returns with bad formatting when used with powershell

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I have been trying the following:

```
   process=check_output(["powershell.exe", "Get-Childitem C:\\Windows\\*.log"]);
           return process
```

it returns with an out put of:

> > > b'\r\n\r\n    Directory: C:\Windows\r\n\r\n\r\nMode                LastWriteTime         Leng
> > >       th Name                                                                  \r\n----                -------------         -
> > >       ----- ----                                                                  \r\n-a----        6/14/2018  11:26 AM
> > >           4056 DtcInstall.log                                                        \r\n-a----        6/21/2018  11:33 AM
> > >             41261 iis.log                                                               \r\n-a----        9/12/2016   4:34 AM
> > >                 1342 lsasetup.log                                                          \r\n-a----        6/25/2018  12:06
> > >       PM           8904 PFRO.log                                                              \r\n-a----        6/21/2018  12:
> > >       04 PM           7530 setupact.log                                                          \r\n-a----        9/12/2016
> > >        4:35 AM              0 setuperr.log                                                          \r\n-a----        6/26/201
> > >       8  12:17 PM            275 WindowsUpdate.log                                                     \r\n\r\n\r\n'

with \n and \r all over the place. How do I get it to return with the standard desired formatting? I have also tried the subprocess Popen method with .PIPE, which gave the same result.

Comment: You could try:

`process=check_output(["powershell.exe", "Get-Childitem C:\\Windows\\*.log"]).strip();` or parse the output line by line as mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422572/python-subprocess-output-without-n

Answer (score 0):

The result is a encoded bytestring, you have to `.decode()` it first, then `print()` it to see it formatted. `\r\n` are line breaks within the string.

```
process = check_output(["powershell.exe", "Get-Childitem C:\\Windows\\*.log"]);
print(process.decode('utf-8'))
```