# Problem with setting file name and extension

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm having a strange problem with setting the correct file name for my file logs. I keep getting a "?" inserted before the extension and I have no idea why. For example, "17-09-19?.log".

I attempted to correct it by trying some concatenation tricks, but it's no use. This code is being run on CentOS.

```
 fileDate = subprocess.check_output(['date', '+%d-%m-%Y'])
 file = open(fileDate +".log","a+")
 file.write(someData)
 file.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python subprocess output without \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422572/python-subprocess-output-without-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date +%d-%m-%Y` command returns the date string plus a newline (`\n`) character at the end. Then Python's [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) simply passes the entire result (including the `\n`) back to you. On Linux, a `?` means that the command you are using to display the filename found an unprintable character (in this case, the `\n` character) and printed a `?` instead.

If you just wanted to create filenames based on dates, you don't need to fire off a subprocess to call the `date` command, just use Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. It also supports [formatting date/time strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) like the `date` command.

```
from datetime import datetime

fileDate = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
print(type(fileDate), fileDate)  # <class 'str'> 18-09-19

file = open(fileDate + ".log", "a+")
file.write(someData)
file.close()
```